# Selenium search data from a table element

Tags: python, mysql, selenium, mysql-python, pymysql

I m trying to find and fill form with Selenium but I have to select id from a mysql table. There is no problem to fetchone item with mysql. The problem is when I add variable to selenium code, it gives me this error:

> Invalid locate values passed in.

Here is my code:

```
import pymysql
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='xxx', db='python')
cur = conn.cursor()


z=1
cur.execute("SELECT id_1 FROM deneme WHERE id=%s" %(z))
search = cur.fetchone()


chromedriver = 'C:\\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get('https://e-okul.meb.gov.tr/')
a = input ("input something when the page is loaded")
Y = input ("write your comments")
element = find_element_by_id(search)
element.send_keys (y)
```

It is probably because of the fetchone code gives the element with some 
punctuation. But how can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: It should be `element = browser.find_element_by_id(search)`

Comment: It is browser.find, I wrote it to site wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding [0] at the end of the `fetchone()` method call.

```
search = cur.fetchone()[0]
```